# Unlink multiple file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to unlink multiple file in my folder.

I just tried this

```
unlink {000003..006707}.png
```

But I'm getting this.

> unlink: extra operand ‘000004.png’

Comment: What does `man unlink` tell you about the parameters to the command?

Comment: ...and why are you using `unlink` instead of `rm`?

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the man page I don't think it supports that usage.

```
NAME
       unlink - call the unlink function to remove the specified file

SYNOPSIS
       unlink FILE
       unlink OPTION
```

I'd do it using either a for loop or `xargs`.

```
$ for i in {000003..006707}.png; do unlink $i; done
```

If you're just trying to delete a bunch of files you can use `rm {000003..006707}.png`.

Answer (score 1):

slm is correct: `unlink` only supports single file as argument:

```
$ unlink f1.txt f2.txt                                                                                                   
unlink: extra operand ‘f2.txt’
Try 'unlink --help' for more information.
```

So the issue isn't with your `bash` syntax, but with just the way `unlink` is built. As an alternative, use a `for` loop or use `rm`, which does support multiple files passed as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

From `man unlink`:

```
SEE ALSO
       unlink(2)

       Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/unlink>
       or available locally via: info '(coreutils) unlink invocation'
```

From `info '(coreutils) unlink invocation'`:

> ‘unlink’ deletes **a single specified file name**.  It is a minimalist
>   interface to the system-provided ‘unlink’ function.  *Note
>   (libc)Deleting Files::.  Synopsis: It avoids the bells and whistles of
>   the more commonly-used ‘rm’ command (*note rm invocation::).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
find {000003..006707}.png -maxdepth 1 -exec unlink '{}' \;
```

Do notice, however, this method is slower than `rm`.